# How to use LINQ "where select into" syntax in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an object to post to my api, this is my request class.

```
public class MyItem
{
    
    public int CustomerId{ get; set; }
    public string Desc{ get; set; }
    public List<ReceiptDetailItem> receiptDetails{ get; set; }
}

public class ReceiptDetailItem
{
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

}
```

I need to use where clause in OrderDetails, because I only want it's matching details to be posted.

```
  await generalService.POSTAPI(
          url: "POSTMyItem",
          body: {
            "CustomerId": receipt[0]['CUSTOMERID'].toString(),
            "DESC": receipt[0]['DESC'].toString(),
            "OrderDetails": receiptDetailItem
                .where((element) =>
                    element["LOCALRECEIPTID"] ==
                    receipt[0]['LOCALRECEIPTID'])
                .toSet()
                .toList()
                .map((e) => 
                receiptDetails(
                    unitId: e["unitId"],
                    amount: e["amount"]
                   ))
          },
        ).then((value) async {...
```

Basically I want to use where select toList in flutter and create my receiptDetails in list type, but it doesnt work, returns <type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Does the request fail on parsing the response, or it fails on building the body?

Comment: it fails on building body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem like this:

```
  await generalService.POSTAPI(
              url: "POSTMyItem",
              body: {
                "CustomerId": receipt[0]['CUSTOMERID'].toString(),
                "DESC": receipt[0]['DESC'].toString(),
                "OrderDetails": receiptDetailItem
                    .where((element) =>
                        element["LOCALRECEIPTID"] ==
                        receipt[0]['LOCALRECEIPTID'])
                    .toList()
                    .map((e) => 
                   return {
                        unitId: e["unitId"].toString(),
                        amount: e["amount"].toString()
                        };
              }).toList()
            }).then((value) async {
```